# Transcripts of Futurama

Tags: futurama

Why are there transcripts of un-aired Futurama episodes?  un-aired as in they will be aired later on in the future?

http://theinfosphere.org/Episode_Transcript_Listing

I didn't read through them because of it can spoil the episode for me.  But why does the transcript come up before the episode airs?

Comment: They document that they're just from previews right at the top of the transcripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't transcripts of the full episode... yet.

They are transcripts of released clips from the forthcoming episodes, i.e. [The Butterjunk Effect](http://theinfosphere.org/Transcript%3aThe_Butterjunk_Effect):

> This transcript is based on the Countdown to Futurama post "Leela and Amy Kissing Fry Clip" - of 5 June 2012.

The rest are the same - just existing clips.